# Shunt measurement with differential ADC

Tags: adc, measurement, shunt

For a hobby project that I am doing, I would like to measure the voltage across a shunt resistor with a differential ADC. I am thinking to use the ADS1292 of TI.

However, I have the following question. Since I also expect a negative voltage across the shunt resistor. I would like to generate a bipolar reference Voltage for the ADC

How can I best accomplish that? I have a 4.5V power supply and want to use a rail splitter. Is that stable enough for a precision measurement? If there is a better way of doing that I am open to suggestions.

Best Regards

[EmbedWise](https://www.embedwise.com)

Embedded Systems Enthusiast

Comment: Could we see some schematics? Is the voltage on the terminals of the ADC lower than Vss?

Comment: Currently, I only have a block schematic and I am looking at the common mode input range. If I use it in differential mode then the voltage across the shunt should not increase above the Vss if I am correct. So even if the line voltage is e.g. 20V if the voltage across the shunt does not exceed Vss I am good right?

Comment: Why the ADS1292?

Comment: Because of the cost/resolution ratio. Other suggestions are welcome

Comment: I found a nice article about current sensing techniques [link](http://www.electronicdesign.com/test-measurement/choose-right-current-measurement-technique-your-application). This also gives the answer for the Common mode input range. I cannot assume that if the Line/Bus voltage is above Vss my design will work. I will need the reexamine my assumptions. Anybody has an idea how this dealt with in the uCurrent design [link](http://www.eevblog.com/files/uCurrentRev5schematic.pdf)

Comment: You're better off using a shunt measurement IC like INA199 and putting that to an ADC. That'd be the proper way.